# Why jQuery hide() not work but fadeOut() works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLLvzps2/)

Why `hide()` not working? When I try change `hide()` to `fadeOut()` then it's working. Why?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").hover(function() {
    $(".submenu").hide();
    $(this).find(".submenu").first().show();

    $(".hlavnaKategoria").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });

  $(".submenu").mouseleave(function() {
    $(".submenu").hide(); // whi this not work?? Try change it to fadeOut()
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,700&subset=latin,latin-ext);
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.bold,
.strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.padding20 {
  padding: 20px;
}
.padding10 {
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #1B6CBF;
  height: 100px;
}
.big {
  font-size: 18pt;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #323232;
  text-align: right;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
.menu ul li.hlavnaKategoria {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}
.menu ul li.hlavnaKategoria .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 201px;
  width: 800px;
  background: #323232;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.submenu-item-box {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid silver;
}
.submenu-item-box:hover {
  border-left: 5px solid #1B6CBF;
}
.submenu-item-box a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #fff;
}
li.hlavnaKategoria.active {
  background-color: #323232;
  border-right: 0px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="kategorie">
    <li class="hlavnaKategoria toggle" data-submenu="14">
      <a class="">Menu 1</a>
      <div class="submenu" id="sm_14">
        <div class="padding10 inline submenu-item-box">
          <div class="">Submenu 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hlavnaKategoria toggle" data-submenu="35">
      <a class="">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="submenu" id="sm_35">
        <div class="padding10 inline submenu-item-box">
          <div class="">Submenu 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding10 inline submenu-item-box">
          <div class="">Submenu 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you a use *hover* function a bit wrong.
First, if you output log to see when call your functions, you can see that your mouse leave not calling, because to fire it you should be over element with class *submenu*. So, this element inside *toggle* and when you leave it you also leave element with *toggle* class, that raise *hover* function again.

In case *fadeOut* animation was delay, and really you hide element after calling *show* function. In case *hide* you hide element, and show it instant.

To solve you should use [`hover` with handlerIn, handlerOut params](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover-handlerIn-handlerOut) and show in handerIn and hide in handlerOur.

Sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggle").hover(function() {
    console.log('hover in');
    $(this).find(".submenu").first().show();
    $(this).addClass("active");
  },function(){
    console.log('hover out');
    $(".hlavnaKategoria").removeClass("active");
    $(".submenu").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,800,600,700&subset=latin,latin-ext);
 html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11pt;
}
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 0%, rgba(229, 229, 229, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5', GradientType=0);
}
.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.bold,
.strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.padding20 {
  padding: 20px;
}
.padding10 {
  padding: 10px;
}
.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #1B6CBF;
  height: 100px;
}
.big {
  font-size: 18pt;
}
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #323232;
  text-align: right;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: inherit;
}
.menu ul li.hlavnaKategoria {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 10px;
}
.menu ul li.hlavnaKategoria .submenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 201px;
  width: 800px;
  background: #323232;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
.submenu-item-box {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid silver;
}
.submenu-item-box:hover {
  border-left: 5px solid #1B6CBF;
}
.submenu-item-box a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #fff;
}
li.hlavnaKategoria.active {
  background-color: #323232;
  border-right: 0px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <ul class="kategorie">
    <li class="hlavnaKategoria toggle" data-submenu="14">
      <a class="">Menu 1</a>
      <div class="submenu" id="sm_14">
        <div class="padding10 inline submenu-item-box">
          <div class="">Submenu 1</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="hlavnaKategoria toggle" data-submenu="35">
      <a class="">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="submenu" id="sm_35">
        <div class="padding10 inline submenu-item-box">
          <div class="">Submenu 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="padding10 inline submenu-item-box">
          <div class="">Submenu 2</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: 'mouse leave not calling' it was calling or else fadeout would never be called.

Comment: @TrygveSkogsholm, no, this was called only if before we over it, but, submenu - is part right, and if we just over menu1, menu2 links, `submenu.leave` not raised. So really, if remove _mouseleave_ event handler from source sample, nothing changes, _fadeOut_ is still work, and  _hide_ - not

Comment: It is impossible to remove the mouseleave event handler from source and yet fadeout still works. `fadeOut` and `hide` are only called from the mouseleave event handler. There is no automatic hiding or fading.

Comment: @TrygveSkogsholm, they called in `hover` handler

Comment: @TrygveSkogsholm, i not quite understand what you mean :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like `show()` is being called after `hide()` because for some reason a hover event on the root menu is triggered after mouseleave. Look at the output from this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle").hover(function(){
        $(".submenu").hide();
    $('body').append('hovering, calling show() <br/>');
        $(this).find(".submenu").first().show();

        $(".hlavnaKategoria").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }); 

    $(".submenu").mouseleave(function(){
    $('body').append('mouse left, calling hide() <br/>');
        $(".submenu").hide(); // whi this not work?? Try change it to fadeOut()
    });
});
```

I checked with fadeout and the same thing happens, I think it looks like it 'works' because show() refuses to interrupt the animation. After the animation is done new hover events will revert the transparency but not while it is an intermediate value like 50%.

Solution? the hover event has both an in and an out handler. http://api.jquery.com/hover/ Hopefully the timing is correct on those. i.e. your out handler can hide the submenu and that will be the end of it.